# modifying data before saving , before_create_object in flask-rest-jsonapi

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, json-api

I am trying to make the timezone naive data as timezone aware before saving into the database using **flask-rest-jsonapi**.

This is what I have tried upto now :

```
class EventList(ResourceList):
    def before_create_object(self, data, view_kwargs):
       starts_at = data['starts_at']
       ends_at = data['ends_at']
       zone = data['timezone']
       local = timezone(zone)
       start_time = local.localize(starts_at)
       end_time = local.localize(ends_at)
       data['starts_at'] = start_time
       data['ends_at'] = end_time
       print ("starts_at :"+str(starts_at)+"\n"+
              "ends_at :"+str(ends_at)+"\n"+
              "start_time :" + str(data['starts_at'])+"\n"+
               "end_time :" 
               +str(data['ends_at'])+str(type(data['ends_at'])))
```

but still it isn't being saved.
The final output is :

```
starts_at :2017-07-06 11:22:33
ends_at :2017-07-16 11:22:33
start_time :2017-07-06 11:22:33+05:30
end_time :2017-07-16 11:22:33+05:30<type 'datetime.datetime'>
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py:2029: SAWarning: Usage of the 'collection append' operation is not currently supported within the execution stage of the flush process. Results may not be consistent.  Consider using alternative event listeners or connection-level operations instead.
  % method)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py:2029: SAWarning: Usage of the 'related attribute set' operation is not currently supported within the execution stage of the flush process. Results may not be consistent.  Consider using alternative event listeners or connection-level operations instead.
  % method)
```

Data in database is being saved as :

```
  "ends_at": "2017-07-16T05:52:33+00:00"
  "starts_at": "2017-07-06T05:52:33+00:00"
```

However it should be :

```
  "ends_at": "2017-07-16T05:52:33+05:30"
  "starts_at": "2017-07-06T05:52:33+05:30"
```

cause I am passing `timezone` as :**Asia/Kolkata**

### Update

However one thing I tried now i.e. `data['topic'] = 'new topic'`
and it did change the topic . See the output :

```
"attributes": {
      "topic": "new topic",
      "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
~~~<snip>~~~
```

Comment: what's your db type? mysql or postgresql?

Comment: @Tiny.D
Actually I found out the solution it is that the database is always saving in UTC . The database is postgresql

Comment: great, that's what I want to share with you :)

Comment: @Tiny.D
Any idea how I can save timezone aware datetime object into postgresql ?
Apart from saving timezone in one other column